# Add a paremater to entire wordpress URLS

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find a way to add a paremater to all wordpress URLS.

The code i tried was added to functions.php, however it keeps causing a redirect loop error.

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect(){
    
        $location = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('refpin' => '123',)));
        wp_redirect($location);
    
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```

The goal is to have every URL automatically have a code attached to the URL.

Such as

`https://WEBSITEHERE.TLD?refpin=29922`

I also need to take into consideration that there may be other parts of the site that has a `?something=`

so in that case it would need to add `&refpin=123`

I cant seem to get it to work, without the redirect loop issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect(){
    
        $location = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('refpin' => '123',)));
        wp_redirect($location);
    
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```

Comment: _"however it keeps causing a redirect loop error"_ - so check first, if that parameter is _already_ present in the current URL - and if so, _don't_ redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to check if a query parameter is in the url together with [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) this will help you with the redirect issues.

example:

```
function wprdcv_param_redirect(){

        if( !isset( $_GET['refpin'] ) ){
           $location = esc_url(add_query_arg(array('refpin' => '123',)));
           wp_redirect($location);
        }
    

    
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wprdcv_param_redirect');
```